# Unable to scroll though page, even with overflow

Tags: html, css

Im making a website [here](http://psrt.to/ref) and im using css for the card containers, but when it is viewed on a smaller screen or when the cards do not fit inside of one page I cant scroll up or down. I've looked at the scroll-behavior and tried but it won't let me change it even with that on "auto". I'm using chrome for testing.

heres the example:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  padding: 1px;
  align-content: space-evenly;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(400px, 1fr));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@nimiq/style@v0.8.2/nimiq-style.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="nq-card">
    <div class="nq-card-header">
      <button class="nq-button light-blue">Test</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nq-card">
    <div class="nq-card-header">
      <button class="nq-button light-blue">Test</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nq-card">
    <div class="nq-card-header">
      <button class="nq-button light-blue">Test</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nq-card">
    <div class="nq-card-header">
      <button class="nq-button light-blue">Test</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Pika, you really need to post a [reprex], as no one on SO is going to debug your online site...downvote and closure of your question will be the result. Sorry, but this is how it works on SO.

Comment: ah ok ill put one here right now

Comment: aight i put the example there.

Comment: Your code scrolls perfectly now here in SO (and outside in my browser).... Maybe put `<body></body>` around your divs?

Comment: i was messing around with the css on it, seems it works on the snippet runner and on the w3schools tryit editor where the scrollbar shows up and im able to scroll, but when i visit it on my browser using the live version it doesn't show the scrollbar. I provided a link to the live version that wasn't scrolling

Comment: updated the live one to have the `<body> </body>` under the header tags, still doesn't scroll or show the scrollbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet with corrected structure runs fine on SO and 'live' in the browser...

In your (full) running code  both `<html>` and `<body>` have CSS set `overflow: hidden`. Remove/disable that CSS (class `.stuck` used on `body`) and you should be able to scroll.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1">

<title>SO62866913</title>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@nimiq/style@v0.8.2/nimiq-style.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<style>
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  padding: 1px;
  align-content: space-evenly;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(400px, 1fr));
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="nq-card">
            <div class="nq-card-header">
                <button class="nq-button light-blue">Test</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="nq-card">
            <div class="nq-card-header">
                <button class="nq-button light-blue">Test</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="nq-card">
            <div class="nq-card-header">
                <button class="nq-button light-blue">Test</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="nq-card">
            <div class="nq-card-header">
                <button class="nq-button light-blue">Test</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ah, this solved the problem